# Getting unique values from specific point in a nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, renpy

I have a list like this:

```
$ mylist = [(u'nr',<object>,'string1'),(u'fm',<object>,'string2'),(u'nr',<object>,'string3')]
```

I would like to get the unique values of `nr`and `fm` from that list (ie, no repeat ones for that first element).

I've been looking at getting unique lists using `set()` and such, and I tried this (from another thread):

`$ unique = reduce(lambda l, x: l.append(x) or l if x not in l else l, mylist, [])`

but that didn't work.

Was asked to clarify: I want ['nr','fm'] in the final result

Comment: `set(mylist)` should do right?!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Can you provide the expected output for your example? Do you expect ['nr', 'fm'], or [(u'nr',<object>,'string'),(u'fm',<object>,'string')]? 

Does the value of <object> matter when deduplicating?

Comment: updated and clarified

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran no, that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will yield the unique, first values of a list of tuples:

```
set(x[0] for x in mylist)
```

If you want it back to a list:

```
list(set(x[0] for x in mylist))
```

Comment: No. First off, I would need to know what the list contains beforehand. I don't. (I could manage to set that up, but would prefer not to). Also, I don't want the sets, I just want the first value of each tuple. And only unique ones at that.

Comment: Updated answer in response to your udpated question

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
list(set(tpl[0] for tpl in mylist))
```

**Explanation:**
Break the problem into stages:

1. Get all items at index 0 from you nested lists:

   ```
   first_items_in_nested = (tpl[0] for tpl in mylist)
   ```
2. Get the unique values from step 1:

   ```
   unique_items = set(first_items_in_nested)
   ```
3. (optional) Convert results back to a list:

   ```
   result = list(unique_items)
   ```